# Woocommerce Intuit QBMS payment causing loop error with only home page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, intuit-partner-platform

So when I activate the Woocommerce Intuit QBMS payment Gateway all my pages work just fine except the home page.  My theme is set for static with Home as the main page.  when You go to it, it is creating a permanent 301 redirect to itself that never ends.  This only happens when the plugin is active.  I have no clue where to even start troubleshooting this since every other page other then the home page works just fine.  I have also looked for plugin conflict and even with every plugin disabled other then the Intuit QBMS plugin it still does not work.  Any code needed I can provide.  Just need help to know even where to look.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I haven't tested it thoroughly yet, but leaving "Un-force HTTPS when leaving the checkout" unchecked avoids the redirect loop for me. (It is checked by default when you force SSL.)